# Slow query SQL Server 2016

Tags: query-performance, sql-server-2016

I have a query that is taking more than 7 hours and doesn’t finish, as it doesn’t finish I can’t generate the actual execution plan.

[Here's brentozar's Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJJGeBFf_)

It has a temporary table, and then a SELECT that inserts into the Temporary table.

```
 CREATE TABLE #Result (
     SEQ_RESULT              INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     NUM_PROCES              CHAR (20)           NOT NULL,
     DES_SISTEM_PROCES       VARCHAR (10)        NOT NULL,
     IDE_GRAU                CHAR (1)            NULL,
     COD_CLASSE_CNJ          INT                 NULL,
     COD_ORGAO_JULGAD_CNJ    INT                 NULL,
     COD_ASSUNT_CNJ          INT                 NULL,
     NUM_CPF_MAGIST          CHAR (11)           NULL,
     IDE_TEMPO               INT                 NULL,
     COD_MATERI              INT                 NULL,
     COD_EVENTO_CNJ          INT                 NULL,
     COD_ORGAO_GABINE_CNJ    INT                 NULL,
     SEQ_DESCRI_GABINE       INT                 NULL,
     SEQ_PROCES_FASE         INT                 NULL,
     DAT_HORA_FASE           DATETIME            NULL,
     DAT_HORA_FASE_ORGAO_PRINCI          DATETIME            NULL,
     COD_EVENTO_COMPLE_CNJ   INT                 NULL,
     COD_RESULT_CNJ          INT                 NULL,
     DAT_AUX_1               DATETIME            NULL,
     DAT_AUX_2               DATETIME            NULL,
     SEQ_PROCES              INT                 NULL, 
     SEQ_PROCES_INDICA       INT                 NULL,
     SEQ_FASE                BIGINT              NULL,
    EVENTO_0001 BIGINT NULL,EVENTO_0002 BIGINT NULL,
    EVENTO_0001_LOCAL BIGINT NULL,EVENTO_0002_LOCAL BIGINT NULL,
     EVENTO_PRINCIPAL        INT NULL,
     EVENTO_ORGAO_PRINCIPAL  INT NULL,
     EVENTO_FASE_AUX1        INT NULL,
     EVENTO_FASE_AUX2        INT NULL
);





INSERT INTO #result
        (
                    num_proces,
                    des_sistem_proces,
                    ide_grau,
                    cod_classe_cnj,
                    cod_orgao_julgad_cnj,
                    cod_assunt_cnj,
                    num_cpf_magist,
                    ide_tempo,
                    cod_materi,
                    cod_evento_cnj,
                    cod_orgao_gabine_cnj,
                    seq_descri_gabine,
                    seq_proces_fase,
                    dat_hora_fase,
                    dat_hora_fase_orgao_princi,
                    cod_evento_comple_cnj,
                    cod_result_cnj,
                    dat_aux_1,
                    dat_aux_2,
                    evento_0001,
                    evento_0002,
                    evento_principal,
                    evento_orgao_principal,
                    evento_fase_aux1,
                    evento_fase_aux2
        )
SELECT num_proces,
   des_sistem_proces,
   ide_grau,
   cod_classe_cnj,
   cod_orgao_julgad_cnj,
   cod_assunto,
   num_cpf_magist,
   ide_tempo,
   cod_materi,
   cod_evento_cnj,
   cod_orgao_gabine_cnj,
   cod_descri_gabine,
   seq_proces_fase,
   dat_hora_fase,
   dat_hora_fase_orgao_principal,
   cod_evento_comple_cnj,
   cod_result_cnj,
   dat_aux_1,
   dat_aux_2,
   evento_0001,
   evento_0002,
   tabela_principal,
   tabela_orgao_principal,
   tabela_auxiliar_1,
   tabela_auxiliar_2
FROM   (
                            
    SELECT
        NUM_PROCES,
        (   SELECT
            TOP 1 DES_SISTEM_PROCES   
        FROM
            T_FASES_CALCULO  
        WHERE
            IDE_GRAU = BASE.IDE_GRAU 
            AND NUM_PROCES = BASE.NUM_PROCES 
            AND DAT_HORA_FASE <= '2021-01-31 23:59:59.997'  
        ORDER BY
            SEQ  ) AS 'DES_SISTEM_PROCES',
        IDE_GRAU,
        SEQ_PROCES,
        SEQ_PROCES_GRAU,
        COD_CLASSE_CNJ,
        COD_ORGAO_JULGAD_CNJ,
        (SELECT
            TOP 1 HA.COD_ASSUNT_CNJ 
        FROM
            HIST_PROCESSO_ASSUNTO HA 
        WHERE
            HA.IDE_ASSUNT_PRINCI = 'S' 
            AND HA.NUM_PROCES = BASE.NUM_PROCES 
            AND HA.DES_SISTEM_PROCES = BASE.DES_SISTEM_PROCES 
            AND HA.TIP_OPERA = 'E' 
            AND HA.DAT_ASSUNT_MOVIME <= BASE.DAT_HORA_FASE 
        ORDER BY
            HA.DAT_ASSUNT_MOVIME DESC) AS COD_ASSUNTO,
        NUM_CPF_MAGIST,
        1225 AS IDE_TEMPO,
        COD_MATERI,
        COD_EVENTO_CNJ,
        COD_ORGAO_GABINE_CNJ,
        (SELECT
            TOP 1 SEQ_DESCRI_GABINE 
        FROM
            D_DESCRICAO_GABINETE GAB 
        WHERE
            GAB.COD_GABINE_CNJ = BASE.COD_ORGAO_GABINE_CNJ 
            AND (
                (
                    BASE.DAT_HORA_FASE >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                    AND GAB.DAT_INICIO <= BASE.DAT_HORA_FASE
                ) 
                OR (
                    BASE.DAT_HORA_FASE < '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                    AND GAB.DAT_INICIO <= '2021-01-31 23:59:59.997'
                )
            ) 
        ORDER BY
            DAT_INICIO DESC) AS COD_DESCRI_GABINE,
        SEQ_PROCES_FASE,
        DAT_HORA_FASE,
        DAT_HORA_FASE_ORGAO_PRINCIPAL,
        COD_EVENTO_COMPLE_CNJ,
        COD_RESULT_CNJ,
        DAT_AUX_1,
        DAT_AUX_2,
        EVENTO_0001,
        EVENTO_0002,
        TABELA_PRINCIPAL,
        TABELA_ORGAO_PRINCIPAL,
        TABELA_AUXILIAR_1,
        TABELA_AUXILIAR_2 
    FROM
        ( SELECT
            DISTINCT AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.NUM_PROCES,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.DES_SISTEM_PROCES,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.IDE_GRAU,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ_PROCES,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ_PROCES_GRAU,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.DAT_HORA_FASE as 'DAT_HORA_FASE',
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.DAT_HORA_FASE AS 'DAT_HORA_FASE_ORGAO_PRINCIPAL',
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.COD_EVENTO_CNJ,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.COD_ORGAO_JULGAD_CNJ,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.COD_ORGAO_GABINE_CNJ,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.NUM_CPF_MAGIST,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.COD_EVENTO_COMPLE_CNJ,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.COD_RESULT_CNJ,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ_PROCES_FASE,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.COD_MATERI,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.COD_CLASSE_CNJ,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ,
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.DAT_CARGA,
            NULL AS 'DAT_AUX_1',
            NULL AS 'DAT_AUX_2',
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ_PROCES_FASE AS 'EVENTO_0001',
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0002.SEQ_PROCES_FASE AS 'EVENTO_0002',
            1 as 'TABELA_PRINCIPAL',
            1 as 'TABELA_ORGAO_PRINCIPAL',
            NULL as 'TABELA_AUXILIAR_1',
            NULL as 'TABELA_AUXILIAR_2',
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION 
        BY
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ_PROCES_GRAU 
        ORDER BY
            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ) AS RN 
        FROM
            (SELECT
                REL.* 
            FROM
                ( SELECT
                    * 
                FROM
                    ( SELECT
                        F.COD_CLASSE_CNJ,
                        F.COD_EVENTO_COMPLE_CNJ,
                        F.COD_EVENTO_CNJ,
                        F.COD_MATERI,
                        F.COD_ORGAO_GABINE_CNJ,
                        F.COD_ORGAO_JULGAD_CNJ,
                        F.SEQ_RESULT_COMPLE AS COD_RESULT_CNJ,
                        F.NUM_CPF_MAGIST,
                        REL.DAT_FASE AS DAT_HORA_FASE,
                        REL.SEQ_PROCES_FASE,
                        REL.NUM_REGIST_JUDICI AS NUM_PROCES,
                        REL.IDE_SISTEM AS DES_SISTEM_PROCES,
                        REL.DAT_AUXILI_1 AS DAT_AUX_1,
                        REL.DAT_AUXILI_2 AS DAT_AUX_2,
                        NUM.SEQ_PROCES,
                        NUM.SEQ_PROCES_GRAU,
                        T.SEQ,
                        T.IDE_GRAU,
                        T.DAT_CARGA 
                    FROM
                        F_JUSTICA_NUMERO F WITH (NOLOCK) 
                    JOIN
                        REL_FATO_PROCESSO REL WITH (NOLOCK) 
                            ON F.SEQ_JUSTIC_NUMERO = REL.SEQ_JUSTIC_NUMERO 
                    JOIN
                        SISTEMA_PROCESSUAL S WITH (NOLOCK) 
                            ON REL.IDE_SISTEM = S.DES_SISTEM_PROCES 
                    JOIN
                        NUMERO_PROCESSO NUM WITH (NOLOCK) 
                            ON NUM.NUM_PROCES = REL.NUM_REGIST_JUDICI 
                            AND NUM.SEQ_SISTEM = S.SEQ_SISTEM_PROCES 
                    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT
                        TOP 1 * FROM
                            T_FASES_CALCULO WITH (NOLOCK) 
                        WHERE
                            SEQ_PROCES_FASE = REL.SEQ_PROCES_FASE 
                            OR ( SEQ_PROCES_GRAU = NUM.SEQ_PROCES_GRAU 
                            AND DAT_HORA_FASE = REL.DAT_FASE ) 
                        ORDER BY
                            SEQ ) T 
                    WHERE
                        1=1 
                        AND SEQ_INDICA_COLUNA = 602 
                        AND IDE_TEMPO = 1225 
                    ) UNION_0001) REL ) AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001 
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT
                REL.* FROM
                    ( SELECT
                        * 
                    FROM
                        ( SELECT
                            F.COD_CLASSE_CNJ,
                            F.COD_EVENTO_COMPLE_CNJ,
                            F.COD_EVENTO_CNJ,
                            F.COD_MATERI,
                            F.COD_ORGAO_GABINE_CNJ,
                            F.COD_ORGAO_JULGAD_CNJ,
                            F.SEQ_RESULT_COMPLE AS COD_RESULT_CNJ,
                            F.NUM_CPF_MAGIST,
                            REL.DAT_FASE AS DAT_HORA_FASE,
                            REL.SEQ_PROCES_FASE,
                            REL.NUM_REGIST_JUDICI AS NUM_PROCES,
                            REL.IDE_SISTEM AS DES_SISTEM_PROCES,
                            REL.DAT_AUXILI_1 AS DAT_AUX_1,
                            REL.DAT_AUXILI_2 AS DAT_AUX_2,
                            NUM.SEQ_PROCES,
                            NUM.SEQ_PROCES_GRAU,
                            T.SEQ,
                            T.IDE_GRAU,
                            T.DAT_CARGA 
                        FROM
                            F_JUSTICA_NUMERO F WITH (NOLOCK) 
                        JOIN
                            REL_FATO_PROCESSO REL WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                ON F.SEQ_JUSTIC_NUMERO = REL.SEQ_JUSTIC_NUMERO 
                        JOIN
                            SISTEMA_PROCESSUAL S WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                ON REL.IDE_SISTEM = S.DES_SISTEM_PROCES 
                        JOIN
                            NUMERO_PROCESSO NUM WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                ON NUM.NUM_PROCES = REL.NUM_REGIST_JUDICI 
                                AND NUM.SEQ_SISTEM = S.SEQ_SISTEM_PROCES 
                                AND NUM.SEQ_PROCES_GRAU = AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ_PROCES_GRAU 
                        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT
                            TOP 1 * FROM
                                T_FASES_CALCULO WITH (NOLOCK) 
                            WHERE
                                SEQ_PROCES_FASE = REL.SEQ_PROCES_FASE 
                                OR ( SEQ_PROCES_GRAU = NUM.SEQ_PROCES_GRAU 
                                AND DAT_HORA_FASE = REL.DAT_FASE ) 
                            ORDER BY
                                SEQ ) T 
                        WHERE
                            1=1 
                            AND SEQ_INDICA_COLUNA = 220 
                            AND IDE_TEMPO = 1225 ) UNION_0001) REL 
                    WHERE
                        AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ IS NOT NULL) AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0002 
                    WHERE
                        (
                            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0001.SEQ IS NOT NULL 
                        ) 
                        AND (
                            AUTO_INDICADOR_0647_EVENTO_0002.SEQ IS NULL 
                        ) ) BASE 
                WHERE
                    BASE.RN = 1
                        ) CONSULTA
```

Can anyone help me decrease the query execution time?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Very hard to tell on such a complex query without the actual plan. First things to try: strip out every column and subquery you don't need. There are a bunch of implicit conversions, track them down and work out if they affect anything. `F_JUSICA_NUMERO` is a massive hash join on the inside of a nested loop. Seems to be a lot of tables with no clustered index and single column non-clustered, what's up with that, furthermore, the nested subqueries have no efficient access method so they need a sort. Finally, try a `select top 1000` on the outside and see if you can get an actual plan that way

Comment: Welcome @fernandoSatonni  I'm surprised you can't see the execution plan. Are you using the studio manager activity monitor, then the recent query section? From there I 'usually' can get the execution plan.  Also, Chalieface is correct that this is a truly complex query. If I was in your shoes, I would create #temp1, #temp2, #tempN... and build each table with pieces of the inner queries until I get what I want. Usually along the way I find which query is killing it.

Comment: @D-K It's not possible to get the full *actual* execution plan until the query has finished running since that includes statistics on what actually happened (e.g. how many rows were actually returned from a specific operation vs how many SQL Server thought was going to be returned). Unfortunately that does make debugging performance problems like the one OP is experiencing more difficult. The estimated plan OP linked is showing a warning for a potential **cardinality estimate** issue, which I bet is probably the problem they're facing. If you can get a copy of the **actual execution plan**...

Comment: ...OP, that would be greatly helpful in determining your issue, otherwise if I get a chance I'll try to trace through the estimated execution plan's XML and the query itself to try to determine the source of your issue. As Charlieface suggested, if you can obtain the actual plan by selecting less rows (even a `SELECT TOP 1` might be helpful in getting the actual plan) though there's a chance it generates a different plan without the issue of your current plan, but if it's a **cardinality estimate** issue, then more likely it'll still expose that problem.

Comment: You have many OUTER APPLY in the query, which can be realized only as nested loops. This seems like an analytical query (processing many of rows). You don't want nested loops in those. You need to rewrite the query to get rid of those OUTER APPLY.

Comment: @ J.D, I'm running the query with TOP 1000 and it's been 15 hours and so far it's not over.

I saw that @rois instructed to rewrite the query without the OUTER APPLY to improve the response time, would they show me how I make this change, or another change that makes the query run in less time? thanks

Comment: @FernandoSatonni Sorry I missed your comment to me, it looks like you accidentally added a space after the @ sign. Go for broke, and do a `TOP 1` after every `SELECT` statement in your query and let's see if that comes back with the ***actual* execution plan**. Your query is definitely very over-complicated which is probably part of the problem, so I'll have to take a close look at it when I get a chance and see how you can re-write it to make it better. I'll post an answer when I get a chance to go through it.

Comment: @J.D. It was, I put space ...
These days I was testing as you said, I put TOP 1 in all SELECT, but I still couldn't execute ...

I'm trying to refine the query as mentioned above, without the OUTER APPLY, but I'm not getting it, can you help me with this part?

Thanks.

Comment: @FernandoSatonni Unfortunately your query is a little too complicated for me to look at in depth right now (maybe if I get some time on the weekend, I can take a closer look), but I'll try to help you debug however I can. After reviewing your **execution plan** again, I do see the heaviest **Estimated Number of Rows** operation is an **index scan** on the `NUMERO_PROCESSO` table, and I think specifically it's when you join to it on this line of code `NUMERO_PROCESSO NUM WITH (NOLOCK) ON NUM.NUM_PROCES = REL.NUM_REGIST_JUDICI AND NUM.SEQ_SISTEM = S.SEQ_SISTEM_PROCES`. The **execution plan**...

Comment: ...shows that it thinks that **index scan** operation is going to return almost 10,000,000 rows. So the first question is, does that amount of rows sound possible from that table and the way you're joining to it? Second, can you remove / comment out how you're using that table in the query to test if the performance gets better (then we can focus our attention just on this one part of the query)? And if after commenting it out, the performance does improve, is there a way to pre-filter that table into a **TempTable** first, then index it, and then use that **TempTable** in your query instead?